# Visual Studio detailed version numbers

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm losing my mind.
Most of our development systems have MS Visual Studio Professional 2012 and they report a version number of 
11.0.50727.26. (As seen in the Programs and Features Control Panel.)

However while running a python/psexec reg query script, we discovered a couple of systems report the version number as
11.0.50727.1

When I run the updater (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39305)
Both versions report they are the current version (we want them all to be the same.)

Does anyone know what the last number in the version number actually means?

We use the C++ compiler, but the other pieces are often installed (and not used).

Additionally from within the VS 2012 interface - About, they all report
Version 11.0.61030.00 Update 4

I would like to be able to check on that programmatically using reg queries.

Comment: I believe it's `Major.Minor.Build.Revision` where revision is "the number of two second intervals since midnight in local time".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the C++ compiler is stored in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products\2DF9F6B0548E83946BAE6F3414F3B5FB` with a `Version` that stores the version number as a single DWORD (On my latest updated machine `0b00ee66`). This maps to `11.0.61030` if you use the first word as two numbers and the second as one.

Note that this is only based on some simple regedit searching so apologies if it isn't 100% accurate.

On your other question it appears as though the Programs and Features control panel reports the original installed version, not the current version. It could just be different installation methods stamping a different number, the updates should be used to determine the currently installed version.